# Iteration count for (enhanced) Miller-Rabin

Tags: rsa, public-key, prime-numbers, fips

In [FIPS 186-5 (Digital Signature Standard or DSS)](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf) there is a Table B.1 which specifies the minimum number of rounds of Miller-Rabin testing for 1024, 1536 and 2048 bit keys, used for digital signatures. That's already an update to FIPS 186-4 which specified these numbers up to 1536 bits. However there doesn't seem to be a table for any other values over 2048 bit keys.

**Table B.1. Minimum number of rounds of M-R testing**

| Parameters | Error probability $2^{-100}$ | Error probability $2^{-112}$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 140 bits $p$ and $q$: 1024 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 32 For $p$ and $q$: 4 | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 38 For $p$ and $q$: 5 |
| $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 170 bits $p$ and $q$: 1536 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 27 For $p$ and $q$: 3 | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 41 For $p$ and $q$: 4 |
| $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 200 bits $p$ and $q$: 2048 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 22 For $p$ and $q$: 2 | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 44 For $p$ and $q$: 4 |

The algorithm for calculating the number of rounds is specified in section C.1 of the same document, but it is relatively complex (especially if you have code for the enhanced M-R test but no code to calculate the values).

Could anyone provide the numbers for other common values for these tests? I'm particularly looking for values for 3072, 4096 and 8192 bit keys.

Comment: Note that the -5 is an update to FIPS 186-4, dated start of February this year, where the table was in section C instead of B.

Comment: Do you really mean "to validate an RSA **public** key"?  Well, given a public key, I suppose you might want to make sure it's composite; to do that, a single MR iteration (or Fermat test) will almost certainly be sufficient...

Comment: @poncho I'm trying to validate a key using (the arguably old) NIST 800-89 standard, section 5.3.3 (Explicit) Partial Public Key Validation for RSA, e) Not a power of a prime: Check that n is not a power of a prime, i.e., there are no integers b ≥ 2, c ≥ 2 such that n = bc. This can be done by obtaining an output of COMPOSITE AND NOT A POWER OF A PRIME using the enhanced Miller-Rabin primality test in FIPS 186-3. But I guess that's then just a single round for each test? Uh, yes, that must make sense, sorry. I've removed the "public" part from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [implemented](http://fgrieu.free.fr/tmin.nb) the algorithm in [Appendix C.1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A216%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C648%2C0%5D) and successfully recomputed [table B.1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf), as well as it's [equivalents in FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=81) (notice that the question's rendition of table B.1 has the probability wrong for the right column, butlast and last box, where that probability should be $2^{-128}$ and $2^{-144}$ respectively).

The values for 3072 and 4096-bit keys are those in the second and third rows of cells of table B.1. Here is an extension to common key sizes, also covering obsolete ones.

**Minimum number of rounds of M-R testing for RSA key generation**, assuming trusted random $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$, $q_2$, $p$ and $q$, from FIPS 186-5 table B.1 unless otherwise noted

| Parameters | Error probability $2^{-100}$ | Progressive error probability |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1024-bit public modulus<sup>1,2</sup> $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 100 bits $p$ and $q$: 512 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 38 For $p$ and $q$: 7 | Error probability $2^{-80}$ For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 28 For $p$ and $q$: 5 |
| 1536-bit public key<sup>2,3</sup> $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 120 bits $p$ and $q$: 768 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 35 For $p$ and $q$: 5 | Error probability $2^{-96}$ For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 33 For $p$ and $q$: 5 |
| 2048-bit public modulus $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 140 bits $p$ and $q$: 1024 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 32 For $p$ and $q$: 4 | Error probability $2^{-112}$ For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 38 For $p$ and $q$: 5 |
| 3072-bit public modulus $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 170 bits $p$ and $q$: 1536 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 27 For $p$ and $q$: 3 | Error probability $2^{-128}$ For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 41 For $p$ and $q$: 4 |
| 4096-bit public modulus $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 200 bits $p$ and $q$: 2048 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 22 For $p$ and $q$: 2 | Error probability $2^{-144}$ For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 44 For $p$ and $q$: 4 |
| 6144-bit public modulus<sup>3</sup> $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 230 bits<sup>4</sup> $p$ and $q$: 3072 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 18 For $p$ and $q$: 2 | Error probability $2^{-160}$ For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 47 For $p$ and $q$: 3 |
| 8192-bit public modulus<sup>3</sup> $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ > 260 bits<sup>4</sup> $p$ and $q$: 4096 bits | For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 16 For $p$ and $q$: 1<sup>‡</sup> | Error probability $2^{-176}$ For $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$: 50 For $p$ and $q$: 3 |

<sup>1</sup> From FIPS 186-4.
<sup>2</sup> Obsolete.
<sup>3</sup> Extrapolated, using [FIPS 186-5 appendix C.1](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-5.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A216%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C70%2C648%2C0%5D) for the number of rounds.
<sup>4</sup> This bound is arbitrary. Further, absent any certification requirement, the only rationale for $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ this large seems to be reuse of code for the generation of $p$ and $q$ that requires them. While the use of $p_1$, $p_2$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ could be justifiable when generating $2^{40}$ 1024-bit RSA public keys and requiring infinitesimal probability that any succumbs to a factorization effort concentrating on applying [Pollard's $p-1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_p_%E2%88%92_1_algorithm) or [Williams's $p+1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams%27s_p_%2B_1_algorithm) to many public moduli rather than [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization), or [GNFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) to one modulus, that rationale fails for larger public keys.
<sup>‡</sup> But perhaps make that 2.